# JavaScript create table with id/class+firebase

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a problem with create id or class on my table row. I use Firebase and read data to table in this way.

```
$("#table_body").append(
        "<tr>"+
            "<td>" + doc.data().id + "</td>"+
            "<td>" + doc.data().nazwa + "</td>"+
            "<td>" + doc.data().cena + "</td>"+
            "<td>" + doc.data().ilosc + "</td>"+
        "</tr>"
        );
```

How can I add className or Id to "tr" ?

Comment: To which element you wanna add id?

Comment: I need add id to tr

Answer (score 1):

You should use template strings for this purpose 
here is your code with template strings

```
$("#table_body").append(
        `<tr id=${myIdVariable}>
            <td>${doc.data().id}</td>
            <td>${doc.data().nazwa}</td>
            <td>${doc.data().cena}</td>
            <td>${doc.data().ilosc}</td>
        </tr>`
        );
```

with in a template string you can insert you variable in string like this 
`${variableName}`